# pasar el valor de un select a variable en otro archivo

Tags: php, html, post, get

Tengo el siguiente select. El cual necesito rescatar el valor en otro archivo. lo demas todo lo rescato por post pero este en concreto no puedo.

```
<select class="controls">
  <option selected Required>Sexo</option>
  <option id="frmusexo" name="frmusexo" value="1">Masculino</option>
  <option id="frmusexo" name="frmusexo" value="2">Femenino</option>
  <option id="frmusexo" name="frmusexo" value="3">Prefiero no decirlo</option>
</select>
```

Luego en otro archivo donde quiero pasar la variable no logro rescatar

```
if ($_POST['frmusexo'] ==1){
    $sexo="masculino";
}elseif ($_POST['frmusexo']==2){
    $sexo="Femenino";
}else{
    $sexo="sin especificar";
};
```

form completo:

```
<form class="form-register" id="form1" 
action="../procesaregistro/procesadueño.php" name="form1" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <h4>Formulario Registro</h4>
    <input class="controls" type="text" name="frmunombres" id="frmunombres" placeholder="Ingrese su Nombre" required>
    <input class="controls" type="text" name="frmuapellidos" id="frmuapellidos" placeholder="Ingrese su Apellido" required>
    <input class="controls" type="email" name="frmuemail" id="frmuemail" placeholder="Ingrese su Correo" required>
    <input class="controls" type="text" name="frmurut" id="frmurut" placeholder="Ingrese su rut" required>
    <input class="controls" type="password" name="frmuclave" id="frmuclave" placeholder="Ingrese su Contraseña" required>
    <input class="controls" type="date" name="frmunac" id="frmunac" placeholder="Ingrese su fecha de nacimiento" max="2003-01-01" required>
    <select class="controls">
        <option selected Required>Sexo</option>
        <option id="frmusexo" name="frmusexo" value="1">Masculino</option>
        <option id="frmusexo" name="frmusexo" value="2">Femenino</option>
        <option id="frmusexo" name="frmusexo" value="3">Prefiero no decirlo</option>
    </select>
    <input class="controls" type="tel" pattern="[0-9]{9}" name="frmunumero" id="frmunumero" placeholder="Ingrese su Numero Telefonico" required>
    <p>Estoy de acuerdo con <a onclick="nuevaVentana();">Terminos y Condiciones</a></p>
    <input class="botons" type="submit" value="Registrar" onclick="validarform();">
    <p><a href="../login/logindueño.php">¿Ya tengo Cuenta?</a></p>
</form>
```

Comment: que error te sale y cual es es el resultado esperado?

Comment: Estoy viendo en mi bola de cristal y me parece que te faltan las etiquetas ``<form></form>``

Comment: En este caso no toma el valor seleccionado. Siempre el es valor "sin especificar" independiente de lo que ingrese en el select.

Comment: Si tiene las etiquetas solo que acorte el codigo jaja. <form class="form-register" id="form1" action="../procesaregistro/procesadueño.php" name="form1" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> en concreto es asi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

te recomiendo que le coloces la etiqueta name en el select
En vez de esto

```
<select class="controls">
```

Usa este

```
<select name="frmusexo" class="controls">
```

Seguido a eso, debes de llamar en tu campo.. como normalmente lo haces.